# "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records." when trying to use AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to access my S3 Bucket through the cli. I have everything setup up such as having a `credentials` file where I'm doing this cli work, making sure my environment variables for `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` have the right things in it, and manually setting them using `aws configure`.

`credentials` contains the following information, all blanked out that is:

```
[sts]
aws_access_key_id = ASIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_security_token = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_session_expiration = 2018-11-03T00:21:25+0000
aws_session_token = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ASIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Also just to make sure I have everything setup, I also ran `aws configure`:

```
(venv) ~/.aws $ aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************XXXX shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************XXXX shared-credentials-file
    region  

          us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

However, when I run the following, it says I have this error:

```
(venv) ~/.aws $ aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/my/path ~/my/path
fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

I have no idea how to get around this and exhausted all my Googling options.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Credentials starting with `ASIA` are temporary credentials generated via the Security Token Service, and must be used with a Token.

When you run your `aws s3 sync` command, it is using the [Default] credentials that do not have `aws_security_token` defined.

Try adding `--profile sts` to the command to make it use the [sts] credentials.

Comment: I ended up using Cyberduck to do everything, but I am sure this would have worked so I am giving you the answer.

Comment: One additional note; even if you have your profile set up correctly, but also have `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` environment variables set, you'll want to also set `$AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN`. The profile will be ignored when it sees those env vars.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: waiting 30 min to 1 hour.  Apparently AWS took a while to register that I had created access keys for a user.  After I waited, it worked fine.