# Transfer data from a S3 bucket to a GCP bucket using temporary credentials

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform

I would like to download a public dataset from the [NIMH Data Archive](https://nda.nih.gov/). After creating an account on their website and accepting their Data Usage Agreement, I can download a CSV file which contains the path to all the files in the dataset I am interested in. Each path is of the form `s3://NDAR_Central_1/...`.

## 1 Download on my personal computer

In the [NDA Github repository](https://github.com/NDAR), the [nda-tools](https://github.com/NDAR/nda-tools) Python library exposes some useful Python code to download those files to my own computer. Say I want to download the following file:

```
s3://NDAR_Central_1/submission_13364/00m/0.C.2/9007827/20041006/10263603.tar.gz
```

Given my username (`USRNAME`) and password (`PASSWD`) (the ones I used to create my account on the NIMH Data Archive), the following code allows me to download this file to `TARGET_PATH` on my personal computer:

```
from NDATools.clientscripts.downloadcmd import configure
from NDATools.Download import Download

config = configure(username=USRNAME, password=PASSWD)
s3Download = Download(TARGET_PATH, config)

target_fnames = ['s3://NDAR_Central_1/submission_13364/00m/0.C.2/9007827/20041006/10263603.tar.gz']

s3Download.get_links('paths', target_fnames, filters=None)
s3Download.get_tokens()
s3Download.start_workers(False, None, 1)
```

Behind the hood, the [`get_tokens`](https://github.com/NDAR/nda-tools/blob/50f9cb15da8988aeed49709652d3a08343eae7ea/NDATools/Download.py#L200) method of `s3Download` will use `USRNAME` and `PASSWD` to generate **temporary** access key, secret key and security token. Then, the [`start_workers`](https://github.com/NDAR/nda-tools/blob/50f9cb15da8988aeed49709652d3a08343eae7ea/NDATools/Download.py#L266) method will use the boto3 and s3transfer Python libraries to [download](https://github.com/NDAR/nda-tools/blob/50f9cb15da8988aeed49709652d3a08343eae7ea/NDATools/Download.py#L244) the selected file.

Everything works fine !

## 2 Download to a GCP bucket

Now, say I created a project on GCP and would like to directly download this file to a GCP bucket.

Ideally, I would like to do something like:

```
gsutil cp s3://NDAR_Central_1/submission_13364/00m/0.C.2/9007827/20041006/10263603.tar.gz gs://my-bucket
```

To do this, I execute the following Python code in the Cloud Shell (by running `python3`):

```
from NDATools.TokenGenerator import NDATokenGenerator
data_api_url = 'https://nda.nih.gov/DataManager/dataManager'
generator = NDATokenGenerator(data_api_url)
token = generator.generate_token(USRNAME, PASSWD)
```

This gives me the access key, the secret key and the session token. Indeed, in the following,

- `ACCESS_KEY` refers to the value of `token.access_key`,
- `SECRET_KEY` refers to the value of `token.secret_key`,
- `SECURITY_TOKEN` refers to the value of `token.session`.

Then, I set these credentials as environment variables in the Cloud Shell:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = [copy-paste ACCESS_KEY here]
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = [copy-paste SECRET_KEY here]
export AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN = [copy-paste SECURITY_TOKEN here]
```

Eventually, I also set up the `.boto` configuration file in my home. It looks like this:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
aws_session_token = $AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN
[s3]
calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat
use-sigv4=True
host=s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

When I run the following command:

```
gsutil cp s3://NDAR_Central_1/submission_13364/00m/0.C.2/9007827/20041006/10263603.tar.gz gs://my-bucket
```

I end up with:

> AccessDeniedException: 403 AccessDenied

The full traceback is below:

```
Non-MD5 etag ("a21a0b2eba27a0a32a26a6b30f3cb060-6") present for key <Key: NDAR_Central_1,submission_13364/00m/0.C.2/9007827/20041006/10263603.tar.gz>, data integrity checks are not possible.
Copying s3://NDAR_Central_1/submission_13364/00m/0.C.2/9007827/20041006/10263603.tar.gz [Content-Type=application/x-gzip]...
Exception in thread Thread-2:iB]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/daisy_chain_wrapper.py", line 213, in PerformDownload
    decryption_tuple=self.decryption_tuple)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/cloud_api_delegator.py", line 353, in GetObjectMedia
    decryption_tuple=decryption_tuple)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/boto_translation.py", line 590, in GetObjectMedia
    generation=generation)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/boto_translation.py", line 1723, in _TranslateExceptionAndRaise
    raise translated_exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
AccessDeniedException: AccessDeniedException: 403 AccessDenied
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>A93DBEA60B68E04D</RequestId><HostId>Z5XqPBmUdq05btXgZ2Tt7HQMzodgal6XxTD6OLQ2sGjbP20AyZ+fVFjbNfOF5+Bdy6RuXGSOzVs=</HostId></Error>

AccessDeniedException: 403 AccessDenied
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>A93DBEA60B68E04D</RequestId><HostId>Z5XqPBmUdq05btXgZ2Tt7HQMzodgal6XxTD6OLQ2sGjbP20AyZ+fVFjbNfOF5+Bdy6RuXGSOzVs=</HostId></Error>
```

> I would like to be able to directly download this file from a S3 bucket to my GCP bucket (without having to create a VM, setup Python and run the code above [which works]). Why is it that the temporary generated credentials work on my computer but do not work in GCP Cloud Shell?

The complete log of the debug command

```
gsutil -DD cp s3://NDAR_Central_1/submission_13364/00m/0.C.2/9007827/20041006/10263603.tar.gz gs://my-bucket
```

can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2khp53pmej00vkc/complete_debug_log.txt?dl=0).

Comment: Your .boto file credentials do not include aws_security_token. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @jarmod Thank you, I forgot it in my post. It already is in my `.boto` file.

Comment: The docs are a little confusing and I don't use .boto config files. Is it `aws_security_token` or `aws_session_token`?

Comment: @jarmod I do not think it really matters since the credentials are set in the environment variables. By the way, the log at the end of my post reads:
`DEBUG 1217 15:20:11.074951 provider.py] Using access key found in environment variable.
DEBUG 1217 15:20:11.075263 provider.py] Using secret key found in environment variable.
DEBUG 1217 15:20:11.075522 provider.py] Using security token found in environment variable.`
Therefore, the `.boto` file seems useless for setting S3 credentials here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure you are trying to implement is called  ["Transfer Job"](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#configure)

**In order to transfer a file from Amazon S3 bucket to a Cloud Storage bucket:**

> A. Click the Burger Menu on the top left corner
>
> B. Go to Storage > Transfer
>
> C. Click Create Transfer
>
> 1. Under Select source, select Amazon S3 bucket.
> 2. In the Amazon S3 bucket text box, specify the source Amazon S3 bucket name.
>        The bucket name is the name as it appears in the AWS Management Console.
> 3. In the respective text boxes, enter the Access key ID and Secret key associated 
>        with the Amazon S3 bucket.
> 4. To specify a subset of files in your source, click Specify file filters beneath 
>        the bucket field. You can include or exclude files based on file name prefix and 
>        file age.
> 5. Under Select destination, choose a sink bucket or create a new one.
>
>    - To choose an existing bucket, enter the name of the bucket (without the prefix 
>        gs://), or click Browse and browse to it.
>    - To transfer files to a new bucket, click Browse and then click the New bucket 
>        icon.
> 6. Enable overwrite/delete options if needed.
>
>    By default, your transfer job only overwrites an object when the source version is 
>        different from the sink version. No other objects are overwritten or deleted. 
>        Enable additional overwrite/delete options under Transfer options.
> 7. Under Configure transfer, schedule your transfer job to Run now (one time) or Run 
>        daily at the local time you specify.
> 8. Click Create.

Before setting up the Transfer Job please make sure you have the necessary roles assigned to your account and the required permissions described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#before_you_start).

Also take into consideration that the Storage Transfer Service is currently available to certain Amazon S3 regions, described under the *AMAZON S3* tab, of the *Setting up a transfer job*

Transfer jobs can also be done programmatically. More information [*here*](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-program#transfer_from_to)

Let me know if this was helpful.

**EDIT**

Neither the Transfer Service or `gsutil` command support currently "Temporary Security Credentials" even though they are supported by AWS. A workaround to do what you want is to change the source code of the gsutil command.

I also filed a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/146491391) on your behalf, I suggest you to star it in order to get updates of the procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have said I already tried this. When I follow the steps you listed above, the transfer job fails with `Failed to obtain the location of the source S3 bucket. Additional details: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.` It seems that it is a problem with the access key (and not with roles/rights).

Comment: Searching for that error I found [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/access-key-does-not-exist/) which might be helpful.I also found this [Topic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=771815) in Amazon Discussion Forum. Finally, take a look at these:  [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53127182/11928130) and [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45703954/11928130). What I understand from the above, is that the issue has to do with the temporary credentials you are using.

Comment: Thank you for these links. I also think that the problem must have something to do with the fact that my credentials are _temporary_. Still, as my post suggests, they work on my personal computer. Therefore, I assumed there would be a way of making them work as well on GCP (without having to create a VM to run Python code). Also, from what I understand from the log at the end of my post, my credentials (set in the environment variables) allowed me to connect to the host (`s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`), right?

Comment: I work for Google Cloud Platform Support. Please check the EDIT on my answer.Hope this helped.

Comment: There is still no way to setup `aws_session_token` for gsutil or transfer job.